# homebrew cannot update and I cannot add a git repository

Tags: homebrew

Pretty much what the title says. I'm trying to update homebrew using

```
brew update
```

and I always get the error message

```
$ brew update
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Error: Failure while executing: git checkout -q master
```

The brew doctor command output is as follows:

```
$ brew doctor
Warning: Missing git origin remote.

Without a correctly configured origin, Homebrew won't update
properly. You can solve this by adding the Homebrew remote:
  cd /usr/local
  git remote add origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

When I run

```
cd /usr/local
git remote add origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
```

I get

```
$ cd /usr/local
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

What can I do to get rid of this problem? It seems git doesn't recognize homebrew's repository, put what should I use instead of this suggested one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem, simply cloned the homebrew repository in a temporary location using

```
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
```

and moved the resulting .git directory to /usr/local, overwriting the one already there. After that, I had to checkout a few directories:

```
cd /usr/local
git checkout Library/Formula/
git checkout Library/Contributions/
git checkout Library/ENV/
git checkout Library/Homebrew/
```

Comment: Great answer - thank you. I found that I could remove the broken .git folder rather than mv and overwrite.

Comment: This broke my homebrew and I had to reinstall it.

Comment: Since this answer is from 8 years ago, I assume homebrew works differently now, and this approach is no longer valid. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 30):

Indeed a correct answer but no need to go so far.

As mentioned in the comments also, removing the top **.git** directory present in **/usr/local** is enough. Run your brew update after only having removed the top **.git** directory will rebuild the tree!

Segmentation fault: 11 with your PHP installation is same issue it is still the pulled version from the Mavericks bottle so update and upgrade will correct this and also only needed for your main php55 or php56 and not for all your PHP dependencies installed using Homebrew.

GL!!!

Comment: Confirmed, this answer works as of 30.10.2014 on MacOSX Maverick.

Comment: Removing (actually renaming) the .git directory in /usr/local/ resolved this problem for me on Yosemite. Thanks!